# Visual Studio c++: how to generate function calls with its parameters

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I noticed that the auto-complete options like [Cltr + space] in Visual Studio IDE can only paste function names.
Here is an c++ example code:

```
class  TestClass
    {
    public: 
        explicit TestClass();
        virtual ~TestClass();
        void callThisMethod(int a, char ch, string s);        
    }

// TestClass.cpp file
void TestClass:callThisMethod(int a, char ch, string s){.....}

// main.cpp file:
TestClass tc;
tc.callThisMethod(int a, char ch, string s); // here
```

So is there any way to bring function calls with all necessary parameters.

Answer (score 3):

The Visual Studio correctly designed for what it does:

[image: Visual Studio IntelliSense 1]

The intellisense will make you on the right track by keeping showing the function signature, so that you would know which parameters are actually required. For an instance:

[image: Visual Studio IntelliSense 2]

From the example, it can be clearly seen here that as longer as you type and provide the arguments, the popup will help you to go through the function signature.

Thus, it doesn't seems the feature you're asking is currently available, neither it's required due to the intellisense which actually helps you a lot in this situation.

Comment: Accept this answer @OP. It can't get any better